how to create groups by rolling sum for every <20 in r consider the data as 1:10
consider the following data
data <- data.frame(row=1:10)

   row
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10  10


this is the following code with for loop attempted ,
would like to know if it is possible to replace the for loop with map function
# Initialize variables
rolling_sum <- 0
groups <- numeric(0)
current_group <- 1

# Loop through the data
for (i in seq_along(data$row)) {
  # Add the current value to the rolling sum
  rolling_sum <- rolling_sum + data$row[i]
  
  # If the rolling sum exceeds 20, start a new group
  if (rolling_sum > 20) {
    current_group <- current_group + 1
    rolling_sum <- data$row[i]
  }
  
  # Assign the current group to the element
  groups[i] <- current_group
}

# Print data and groups
data_frame <- data.frame(data, groups)
print(data_frame)


1) Using Reduce at each iteration output the new value, y, negated if the sum, x, plus the new value > 20 and otherwise  output the sum of their absolute values.
The negative values in the result will then represent the starts of new groups so use cumsum on an indicator of negativity to get the group numbers.
This assumes that row is non-negative, which is the case in the question.
library(dplyr)

f <- function(x, y) if (abs(x) + y > 20) -y else abs(x) + y

data %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(Reduce(f, row, acc = TRUE) < 0 )+1)

giving
   row group
1    1     1
2    2     1
3    3     1
4    4     1
5    5     1
6    6     2
7    7     2
8    8     3
9    9     3
10  10     4

2) If the entries in row can be negative then we can't use the sign to signal the group change points but we could store this in the imaginary part of complex numbers.
library(dplyr)

f <- function(x, y) 
  if (Re(x) + y > 20) y+1i else Re(x) + y

data %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(Im(Reduce(f, row, acc = TRUE)))+1)

Update
Revised to reduce restrictions.

Below ae some recursion approaches.

You can define a recursion function helper that cumulatively counts the groups, e.g.,
f <- function(x) {
    helper <- function(k = length(x)) {
        if (k == 1) {
            return(1)
        }
        p <- Recall(k - 1)
        grp <- p[k-1]
        c(p, grp + (sum(x[1:(k - 1)][p == grp]) + x[k] > 20))
    }
    helper()
}

and then run
> transform(data, groups = f(row))
   row groups
1    1      1
2    2      1
3    3      1
4    4      1
5    5      1
6    6      2
7    7      2
8    8      3
9    9      3
10  10      4


If you want to keep track of the recursion progress, say, both the grouping and cumulative sum information, you can make slight modifications like below
f <- function(x) {
    helper <- function(k = length(x)) {
        if (k == 1) {
            return(list(grp = 1, s = x[k]))
        }
        p <- Recall(k - 1)
        grp <- p$grp
        s <- p$s
        if (s[k - 1] + x[k] > 20) {
            list(grp = c(grp, grp[k - 1] + 1), s = c(s, x[k]))
        } else {
            list(grp = c(grp, grp[k - 1]), s = c(s, s[k - 1] + x[k]))
        }
    }
    helper()
}

and you will obtain
> transform(data, groups = f(row))
   row groups.grp groups.s
1    1          1        1
2    2          1        3
3    3          1        6
4    4          1       10
5    5          1       15
6    6          2        6
7    7          2       13
8    8          3        8
9    9          3       17
10  10          4       10

